# Erro na hora de inserir dados com acentuação

Tags: android, web-service, http, acentuação, volley

To enviando os dados por URL para meu *webservice* se eu colocar o caminho pelo navegador web exemplo no Chrome:  `meuwebservice/inserirusu/João_da_Silva/fotógrafo` e chamar um método para para exibir mostra assim:

```
Nome: João da Silva
profi: Fotógrafo
```

Agora quando eu chamo o método a seguir ele me mostra assim:

```
Nome: Jo?o da Silva
profi: Fot?grafo
```

Coloquei para exibir o caminho que estou passando pelo Android e é o mesmo que eu coloco pelo Chrome.

```
 private void inserir(final String edicao) {  edicao = "João_da_Silva/fotógrafo
    showProgressDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            Const.URL_EDITAR_TRABALHADOR+edicao, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            if(response.equal("Alterado"){
               hideProgressDialog();
               finish();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hideProgressDialog();

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

}
```

Como posso resolver isto?

Estava fazendo dar erro para exibir no logcat e me exibiu que esta assim do android

`meuwebservice/inserirusu/Jo?o_da_Silva/fot?grafo`

mais eu exibi antes de enviar e o caminho está correto no System

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa codificar a url da forma correta, quando se digita isso na barra de endereços do navegador ele já faz isso automaticamente e por isso funciona.

Você pode usar o [`URLEncoder.encode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) para isso, lembrando que deve codifica apenas as partes que podem ter acento ou outros caracteres especiais

```
String edicao = URLEncoder.encode("João da Silva", "UTF-8") + "/" + URLEncoder.encode("Fotógrafo", "UTF-8");
```

Ele deve resolver também o problema de espaços, que em uma URL deveriam ser substituídos por um sinal de + e não por underline.

Comment: Funcionou quando eu utilizei agora está dando erro exemplo passo `á` e envia assim : `%C3%A1`